# Kendo UI for Angular's Grid memory leak?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I have an Angular 4.1.3 application where in one of the components I have 2 Kendo UI Angular 2 grids.  Everything works fine, but every time I leave the page and then come back, the memory usage increases by about 100 MB.  If I do that a few times, the memory usage increases to the point that the user starts seeing lagging.  I have only one Observable in this component to which I unsubscribe in the ngOnDestroy.

The grids receive about 1000 records of 6-7 columns text data, nothing too big.  The reason I suspect the grids are causing the memory increase is because if I remove them from the page, the memory does not increase.

Has anyone experienced anything similar?  What would be the best way to clear the memory used by this component upon exit?

Thanks.

Comment: Try switching your application to production mode, if not done already. Also, update to the latest release (v1.6.2) of the Grid to see if that makes a difference.